# Laravel datatables helper converting my html tags

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, laravel-8, yajra-datatable

I save my html content like this:

```
<p>It is a long <b>established fact that a re</b></p>
```

into database but when i get from db and use laravel datatable helper, it converts my html like this:

```
&lt;p&gt;It is a long &lt;b&gt;established fact that a re&lt;/b&gt;ader will be distracted by the readable content of a page";
```

I want to get as html and append into a div. Please help if anyone had the same error.

Comment: Can you provide more details? For example, a [mre] so that the community can more easily recreate the issue you are having? Show us your (relevant, minimal) code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am asking about why laravel datatables()->of($Model) helper converting my html code (<p>It is a long <b>) to this(&lt;p&gt;It is a long &lt;). I got my data in jquery datatable load. I need my content as Html. Not like this(&lt;p&gt;It is a long &lt;)

Comment: **It can leave your application vulnerable to XSS attacks**

Answer (score 1):

By default, Laravel DataTables protects us from XSS attack by escaping all our outputs. In cases where you want to render an html content, please use rawColumns Datatables.

you need to use ->rawColumns(['column_name1', 'column_name2'])

https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/raw-columns

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that Laravel's blade template engine encodes HTML entities to prevent XSS attacks. You can try using `{!! $name !!}` instead of `{ $name }` when outputting data from the database. Here is the link: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#html-entity-encoding

In another way, you can try using `{!! html_entity_decode($name) !!}` to output your html.

Comment: But i need this code on jquery. When datatable load from controller i put my all datas on client side. When edit some record i need to append HTML code to div. But datatables()->of($model) helper converts my HTML code (<p>It is a long <b>) to this(&lt;p&gt;It is a long &lt;)